# Why does SQL return week 1 for 1/1/2011?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the DateFirst set to 7. Now when I run the following SQL, it returns week 1:

```
SET DateFirst 7
SELECT DATEPART(wk, '1/1/2011') as WeekNumber
```

I am not sure why this is returning week 1 though, if my start day is set to 7. According to me week 1 should start on the 1/2/2011, which is a Sunday. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

> The week (wk, ww) datepart reflects changes made to SET DATEFIRST.
>   January 1 of any year defines the starting number for the week
>   datepart, for example: DATEPART(wk, 'Jan 1, xxxx') = 1, where xxxx is
>   any year.

So: because it is defined as such.

Edit: You can fix this within SQL-SERVER. Use something like this:

```
DATEPART(wk, 
  DATEADD(day, 
    -( (DATEPART(day, date) + 8 - DATEPART(weekday, date)) % 7 - 1),
    date
  )
)
```

What this code does, is use the current day of the year and the weekday to calculate which day was the first Sunday of the year, then subtracts that day from the current date, giving you a virtual date in which the year started on a Sunday and then takes the week number of that date, which should be equal to the week number according to your definition.

Comment: I see. Is there a way for me to change this? I need the first week to start on the first Sunday of the year.

Comment: I am calling this from SQL itself. I have a large SQL that I can't paste, but basically all I care about is the week number to be correct  for us. Select DatePart(dw, MyDateColumn) from x

Comment: No, you aren't calling the SQL from SQL. You are calling the SQL from some language, one way or another. I'm not saying that fixing it outside SQL will help (it will if you are simply using it for something in the calling code, as you can then process it before using it; it won't if you want to sort on it, for example)

Comment: I am running a sql script, so no, I am not calling it from any other code language.

Comment: Here ya go. I made an edit that uses SQL and some SQL-SERVER functions to calculate the week number you are looking for. I am not sure if it is the most efficient way to do this, but I think it should work.

Comment: Your DateAdd has only 2 parameters, but requires 3.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. Thanks for the help. I owe you one.

Answer (score 2):

There is also ISO week

There are mutually equivalent definitions for week 01:

- the week with the year's first Thursday in it,
- the week with 4 January in it,
- the first week with the majority (four or more) of its days in the starting year, and
- the week starting with the Monday in the period 29 December – 4 January.

If 1 January is on a Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday or Thursday, it is in week 01. If 1 January is on a Friday, Saturday or Sunday, it is in week 52 or 53 of the previous year.

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/iso-week-in-sql-server

Comment: This seems to be the solution.